# Bootstrap layout shifter pattern

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I am trying to create a [layout shifter pattern](https://googlesamples.github.io/web-fundamentals/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/layout-shifter.html) using Bootstrap 4.

I have managed to get 2 colored boxes in the right position maintaining the responsiveness but i am not able to get that 3rd box in the right position.

Please let me know how can i do this. Here is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Layout Shifter</title>
  <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Layout Shifter</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="blue"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
        <div class="red"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
          <div class="purple"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS Code :

```
.blue{
    width:100%;height:1100px;
    background-color:rgb(88, 88, 211);
}
.red{
    width:100%;height:550px;
    background-color:rgb(216, 90, 90);
}
.purple{
    width:100%;height:550px;
    background-color:rgb(168, 68, 214);
}
.orange{
    width:100%;height:550px;
    background-color:rgb(212, 135, 46);
}
.light-blue{
    width:100%;height:550px;
    background-color:rgb(160, 168, 238);
}
.container-fluid{
    padding:0;
}
.img-fluid{
    width:100%;
}
.bg-light{
    background-color: #384f3f !important;
}
.navbar-brand{
    color: white !important;
}
.nav-link{
    color: white !important;
}
.img-responsive{
    max-height:550px; 
    width:100%;
}
.navbar-toggler{
    color:white !important;
    border-color:white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boostrap uses the 12 grid columns system. The problem in your code is that you had one 2 width column + one 10 width column + another 10 width column. The first 2 sat on a single row (2 + 10 = 12). The third onw was beeing pushed down.
In order to achieve the desired affect you need to split the row in 2 column a 2 width and a 10 width column and under the second column insert a new row and place those 2 10 column there (but make them 12 width "col-md-12" so they take the entire space left). Here's the jsfiddle + the code you're intrested in:
https://jsfiddle.net/Iulius90/t7vhza3g/1/

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="red"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="purple"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I Understood how to do it, it worked thanks again :)